# Check if <a> tag has been clicked with PHP

Tags: php, html

How can I check if an `<a>` tag in HTML is clicked in PHP?

I have tried it by `if(isset[$_GET[ "idofLink"])`, but in this case, I get the `else` statement.

#### File file1.php

```
<li class="active"><a name = "profile" href="includes/submit-profile.php">Profile</a></li>
```

#### File profile.php

```
if(isset("profile")){
  // Do something....
} else{
  // Do something else ...
}
```

Comment: I aslo tried to be if(isset($_GET['profile']) but nothing found

Comment: Try to change your url to "includes/submit-profile.php?profile=true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a query part in the link, like `... href="includes/submit-profile.php?submit_profile" ...`, so that later you could check whether *that* link is clicked or not.  So the complete `<li>` element should be like this:

```
<li class="active"><a name = "profile" href="includes/submit-profile.php?submit_profile">Profile</a></li>
```

And this is how you can check whether *that* link is clicked or not:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit_profile'])){
    // do something
}else{
    // do something else
}
```